# Why is pandas not showing 11 rows in the Describe method, How do I fix the output?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

How do I fix the output from pandas.describe() method?

I'm doing some analytics on a excel file with 16084 records. When I run pd.descibe() it loses 11 records and shows a count of 14921. A count of 14921 for account_with_no_state, which should be 14932. A count of 1152 for accounts_with_state, and the two should total 16084. When I use the built in len() function on the column it returns the correct number of 16084 records.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

address_with_accounts = pd.read_excel('private document.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
accounts = address_with_accounts[['Account Name', 'Sold To Street', 'Sold To City', 'Sold To State/Province']]

accounts_with_no_state = accounts[accounts['Sold To State/Province'].isnull()]
accounts_with_state = accounts[accounts['Sold To State/Province'].notnull()]


#print(accounts_with_no_state.head())
print('\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n')
print("number of accounts: ", len(accounts_with_no_state['Account Name']))
print(accounts_with_no_state.describe())
print('\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n')


#print(accounts_with_state.head())
print('\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n')
print("number of accounts: ",  len(accounts_with_state['Account Name']))
print(accounts_with_state.describe())
print('\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n')
```

The output with the top addresses crossed out for privacy:

[image]

EDIT: The records are there, and show up as the correct number under different columns, just not the Account Name column, which is the important one I need information from.

Comment: Your 'Account Name' column probably contains `NaN`, which doesn't get included in the count.

Comment: `accounts_with_no_state = accounts[accounts['Sold To State/Province'].isnull()]`
`accounts_with_state = accounts[accounts['Sold To State/Province'].notnull()]` I've tried with `.notnull()` and `.notna()` which should get rid of all NaN values. Do you think I should check for the python type `None`?

Comment: @root I checked a few different ways for `NaN`s and i got 0 back. `print("Number of NaN: ", len(accounts_with_no_state[accounts_with_no_state['Account Name'] == 'NaN']))`

Comment: Try `accounts['Account'].isnull().sum()` to get a count. You can't directly compare to `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that got the 11 that are missing, i've been looking at the code so long I didn't realise I was looking at the wrong column I applied `.notnull` to

Comment: Your `notnull()` checks are not on the `'Account'` column, so they won't detect nulls there.